# How to fetch data from multiple urls at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function that fetches from a url in React

```
const DataContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [cocktails, setCocktails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCocktailList = async () => {
      const baseUrl = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/';
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}search.php?s=margarita`);
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);
        setCocktails(data.drinks);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error fetching data');

        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchCocktailList();
  }, []);
```

How I'm mapping data so far.

```
const DrinkList = () => {
  const { cocktails } = useContext(DataContext);
  return (
    <div className='drink-list-wrapper'>
      {cocktails.length > 0 &&
        cocktails.map((drink) => {
          return <DrinkItem drink={drink} key={drink.idDrink} />;
        })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

However I want to fetch from this url also `${baseUrl}search.php?s=martini`

I would like a good clean way to do this and set my state to both of the returned data.

Comment: When you fetch `martini` and `setCocktails` with that response should it replace the `margarita` response, or do you want it to add these drinks to some object/array?

Comment: It should not replace. I want cocktails to contain both martinis and margaritas. So I can map them.

Comment: How do you want to handle errors in individual network requests? Should the entire operation fail if one request fails or should it succeed with partial data?

Comment: Ok, then can you please also share your component code so we see what your state objects look like so `setCocktails` can properly merge in the new drinks?

Comment: My first would be it should fail. However I am learning so if its best practice to handle separately then I would go with that.

Comment: I have edited to show more.

Comment: Use redux-saga make clearly your implementation when call multiple API and combine it  into a state value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method which will let you specify the cocktail names as dependencies to the `useEffect` so you can store them in your state and fetch new drink lists if you want new recipes. If not, it'll just be a static state variable.

- I've also added another state variable `errorMessage` which you use to pass an error message in the case of failure.
- Also, [you should include the appropriate dependencies in your `useEffect` hook](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920). The `setState` functions returned by calls to `useState` are stable and won't trigger a re-run of the effect, and the `cocktailNames` variable won't trigger a re-run unless you update it with new things to fetch.

```js
const DataContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [cocktails, setCocktails] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(''); // holds an error message in case the network request dosn't succeed
  const [cocktailNames, setCocktailNames] = useState(['margarita', 'martini']); // the search queries for the `s` parameter at your API endpoint

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCocktailLists = async (...cocktailNames) => {
      const fetchCocktailList = async (cocktailName) => {
        const baseUrl = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php';
        const url = new URL(baseUrl);
        const params = new URLSearchParams({s: cocktailName});
        url.search = params.toString(); // -> '?s=cocktailName'
        const res = await fetch(url.href); // -> 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=cocktailName'
        const data = await res.json();
        const {drinks: drinkList} = data; // destructured form of: const drinkList = data.drinks;
        return drinkList;
      };

      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const promises = [];
        for (const cocktailName of cocktailNames) {
          promises.push(fetchCocktailList(cocktailName));
        }
        const drinkLists = await Promise.all(promises); // -> [[drink1, drink2], [drink3, drink4]]
        const allDrinks = drinkLists.flat(1); // -> [drink1, drink2, drink3, drink4]
        setCocktails(allDrinks);
      }
      catch (err) {
        setErrorMessage(err.message /* or whatever custom message you want */);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchCocktailList(...cocktailNames);
  }, [cocktailNames, setCocktails, setErrorMessage, setLoading]);
};
```

Comment: This works after a quick copy and paste to check. But embarrassing for me as I don't understand parts of it. Such as URLSearchParams, using .flat ect and could never explain it to anyone! Is there a way of stripping this down to a more beginner friendly level?

Comment: It's written that way to be extensible and as a model for learning. There are definitely parts that can be simplified for a more hard-coded approach, but is that what you really want? `URLSearchParams` handles encoding of the search parameters for you. If you want to add more parameters, just add to the object argument in the constructor call. `array.flat()` just flattens a multi-dimensional array however many levels you ask it to. Check out the MDN articles on those two to understand them more. I'll add a few comments to the code.

Comment: Good luck! Some React concepts can be kind of mind-bending. Docs, docs, docs...

Answer (score 4):

First base the data fetch function on a parameter:

```
const fetchCocktail = async (name) => {
  const baseUrl = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/';
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}search.php?s=` + name);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data.drinks;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error fetching data');
  }
}
```

Then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await all results:

```
setLoading(true);
var promises = [
  fetchCocktail(`margarita`),
  fetchCocktail(`martini`)
];
var results = await Promise.all(promises);
setLoading(false);
DrinkList(results);
```

Where `results` will be an array with the responses that you can use on the `DrinkList` function.

Comment: This is what I was going to respond with, but would like to note that `Promise.allSettled` will allow you to handle mixed success/failure, whereas `Promise.all` will reject for any failure

Comment: You should probably also `setLoading(false)` after the try/catch in the `finally` for cleanup

Comment: Nevermind, you keep changing your code. I'll stop commenting until you've finalized all of your edits.

Comment: @jsejcksn finished :D

Comment: I've tried this and its crashing the browser. Maybe because of an infinite loop due to the useEffect hook?

Answer (score 0):

var promises = [
  fetchCocktail(`api1`),
  fetchCocktail(`api2`)
];
var results = await Promise.allSettled(promises);